# Remove preinstalled malicious software from smartphone

Tags: malware, uninstallation, antivirus

I bought a THL T9 Plus recently and get some preintalled apps on it, like YouTube. I thought, that this apps are original, because Google Play client recognised these too. My phone behaved strange in some cases, so I tested it with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.
It found: `Android/Trojan.Spy.Agent.YQ` in system/priv-app/thl_YouTube folder.

Comment: You cannot remove that malware without rooting the device, but you can disable it though. You can do that via Settings -> Apps.

Comment: @Firelord: I already tried it, but after restart I got an error message, that this application stopped. I press OK and popup window comes back again and again. So I decided to allow it again.

Comment: Hmm....I wonder whether you could delete this by using a terminal emulator...

Comment: You could hide them via adb, what should work. But as far as I know just at and over nougat. [Here is the video link](https://youtu.be/fAqmjU_EJ8g) to how you could do it. It's from xda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove or freeze pre-order installed apps you need to *root* your device - without rooting you cannot uninstall system apps (those that came bundled with the OS )

- Use [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/how-to-root-privilege-install-xposed-t3524418) guide to root
- Install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to uninstall. There are other root apps that can do this as well but this app is highly recommended for this as also many other things it can do, which you can read in [Titanium Backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titanium-backup?sort=frequent)

  - [To freeze system apps](http://techbaba.info/disable-system-or-pre-installed-app-in-a-rooted-phone/)
  - Convert you tube app into user app ( see [Can I convert a system app to a user app, uninstall it, or move it to my SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20903/can-i-convert-a-system-app-to-a-user-app-uninstall-it-or-move-it-to-my-sd-card) ) followed by uninstalling it and installing from play store
- Yet another alternative is to flash a [custom ROM](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=xda+thl+t9+plus+ROM&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=zTR3WcWbOsrSvwTlxZXYBg)
  , after due diligence

Comment: Custom ROM is problematic, because some applications need original ROM.